# telerik radscheduler view in wpf

Tags: wpf, telerik, radscheduleview

I am using a telerik `RadScheduleView` control to display employee records
I have also added custom column names Employee name,start date,end date.
Please help me on how to fetch data from the database and display it on the `RadScheduleView` control.
I am new to Telerik control.

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far? Have you read the [telerik documentation on data binding](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-overview.html)? I also do not recall why you refer to columns when using a `RadScheduleView`... Do you mean `RadGridView`?

Comment: I am using RadSchedule view which looks like outlook. I want to display the records in the RadSchedule view control

Comment: I see what you mean, you've create a table `Employee` with the columns Name, StartDate and EndDate. Right? And now you wish to display the employees in the control based on their StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: Yes hanton exactly..Could you please suggest me how to bind the data to the control.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display `Employees` in the `RadScheduleView` you need to bind the `AppointmentSource` to a model representation (`Employee`) of the data from your database. Your model representation must implement [`IAppointment`](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/t_telerik_windows_controls_scheduleview_iappointment.html):

[image: IAppointment Interface]

I suppose you only require the `End` (`Employee.EndDate`), `Start` (`Employee.StartDate`) and `Subject` (`Employee.Name`) members for now.

That is as far as I can help you start off. More information on Telerik `RadScheduleView` database binding can be found in the following articles:

1. [Overview](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-overview.html)
2. [RadScheduleView Types and Sources](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-sources.html)
3. [Table Definitions and Relationships](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-datatier.html)
4. [List item](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-midtier-wpf.html)
5. [Models](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-models.html)
6. [View and ViewModel](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-populating-with-data-binding-to-db-viewmodel-wpf.html)

They even have a sample project for you: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-database-example